# Facing issue in applying Dynamic Content in Azure REST data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have one lookup activity and one Copy data Activity which is using REST linked service to get data from one Rest API.

As, I need to do incremental data, I need to pass max id in the url. So, I have set relative URL as

?id=@dataset().parameters.id

And I am settings Dataset parameter value from Pipeline. Pipeline is working fine but only issue I am facing here is, it is sending to the server - 
@body('dataset46621dd59dc847cd812d0ef8472587e0').parameters.id

So, my issue here is - it is not evaluating expression and setting parameter value.

Please let me know, where I am doing mistake here?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry just wanted more clarity on this , As i understand , you are using REST call in your copy activity and you are using Lookup to get some data which you pass in the body of the copy activity . Can you please add more clarity to the question ?

Comment: Hi,any progress here?

Comment: Yes. Jay. Your suggestion helped me to solve my problem. Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

Please use built-in `concat()` function to construct your relative url:

```
@concat('?id=',dataset().param)
```

[image]